# What are the common compliance standards for software products?

Tags: security

This is a very generic question about software products. I would like to know what compliance standards are applicable to any software product.

I know that question gives away nothing. So, here is an example to what I am referring to.
[CiSecurity Security Certification/Compliance](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=membership.certified) lists out products ceritified by them to be compliant to the standards published at their website, i.e, cisecurity.org. Compliance could be as simple as answering a questionnaire for your product and approved by a thirdparty like cisecurity or it could apply to your whole organization, for instance, PCI-DSS compliance.

I would be very interested in knowing the standards that products you know/designed/created, comply to. To give you the context behind this question: I am the developer of a data-masking tool. The said tool helps mask onscreen html text in a banking web application using filters. So, for instance, if the bank application lists out user information with ssn, my product when integrated with the banking product, automatically identifies ssn pattern and masks it into a pre-defined format.So, I  have my product marketing team wanting more buzz words like compliance to be able to sell it to more banking clients. Hence, understanding **"compliances that apply to products**" is a key research item for me at this point. By which I meant, security compliances.

Appreciate all your help and suggestions.

Comment: I don't understand what the product does but is it W3 compliant? Do you really have a marketing team or is this post just BS compliant?

Comment: its not W3 compliant. Its not a webapp. Yes, I am taking about a product with proper marketing team. No BS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a specific governing body that dictates specifications for your type of software.   Individual countries have their own privacy laws,  and if you are in the US individual states have their own laws, California being the toughest.

It sounds like your software is being distributed.  When someone reports a vulnerability in your software (Yes,  its going to happen eventually).  If the bug was filed by a professional then they probably used Mirte which will reference a CWE number (BugTraq is a nightmare!).  Very few people realize that there are acutely hundreds of different types of vulnerabilities and **all** software is vulnerable to something,  even if its a technicality.  If you think your software is 100% secure then you are a fool or you where fooled by a good salesman.

I believe that the [CWE-200](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/200.html) family is most important to you.  The most important member of this family is [CWE-213](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/213.html) which directly references the example vulnerability you are attempting patch.  [CWE-549](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/549.html) is also similar to what you are trying to defend against.  The important part is to check out this CWE's Relationships because there are a number of related vulnerabilities that apply to you.  For instance CWE-549 issue is related to [credential management](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/255.html).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your in need of finding IF the software in question will be used in an industry that already has compliance standards. For example, Vanguard Configuration Manager is an automated software scanner that enables continuous monitoring of IBM System z security configuration settings. The software supports implementing and utilizing the z/OS and RACF configuration checklist from the National Checklist Program (NCP) of the National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) and the Department of Homeland Security (DHS).

More and more industries and publicly held companies are now having to conform to these federal standards. Chances are if your looking to gain banking clients, you'll have a slew of compliance regulations that must be meet in your software before they even demo it.